# How to iterate through entries in enumeration from a loop

Tags: javascript, angular

i create the below posted color enumeration in a separate file of `.ts` extension. i would like to know how to use or to call the enumeration in the `for-loop` in the posted code in such way that to be able to iterate throw it.
in other words, how to iterate through the enumeration posted below in a loop so that for `ì = 0` `RED` is set and when `i=7` `LIME`is set.

the double question mart, as apparent, is to be replaced be the iteration through the enumeration.

**code**:

```
for(let i = 0; i < centerPointsClusters.length;i++) {
            this.centerPoint = this.APIService.visualisePoint(this.map,centerPointsClusters[i], ??)
        }
```

**enum**:

```
export enum ColorEnum {
    RED = "#F44336",
    PINK = "#FF4081",
    PURPLE = "#9C27B0",
    INDIGO = "#536DFE",
    BLUE = "#2196F3",
    TEAL = "#64FFDA",
    GREEN = "#4CAF50",
    LIME = "#EEFF41",
    YELLOW = "#FFEB3B",
    ORANGE = "#FFAB40"
  }
```

Comment: @R.Richards no it does not.  i want to iterate through the enumeration according to an index of i in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, enum in typescript is basically an object. So you could take the keys and iterate through it

```
import { ColorEnum } from './ColorEnum';
const enumKeys = Object.keys(ColorEnum);

for(let i = 0; i < centerPointsClusters.length;i++) {
    this.centerPoint = this.APIService.visualisePoint(this.map, centerPointsClusters[i], enumKeys[i])
}
```

Comment: i get this error:ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @LetsamrIt I guess you haven't imported the enum yet. `import ColorEnum from './ColorEnum'`

Comment: i imported it as you mentioned. now i am getting empty array

Comment: @LetsamrIt see updated answer although you have to make sure that the filename and the path to your enum file is correct

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an obj instead of enum

```
const obj =  {
RED : "#F44336",
PINK : "#FF4081",
PURPLE : "#9C27B0",
INDIGO : "#536DFE",
BLUE : "#2196F3",
TEAL : "#64FFDA",
GREEN : "#4CAF50",
LIME : "#EEFF41",
YELLOW : "#FFEB3B",
ORANGE : "#FFAB40"
};


const iterateObj = () => {
for(let i in obj) {
    console.log(i, obj[i]);
  }
}
```